# Como remover apenas a scrollbar horizontal da página?

Tags: css, rolamento, electron

Estou criando uma aplicação em Electron e preciso remover da página a *scrollbar* horizontal. Eu tentei utilizar o código CSS abaixo, porém ele remove também o *scrollbar* vertical.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso não remove o scroll, ele oculta, se for para remover o certo seria aplicar direto no elementos:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Aplicamos em ambos porque no Chrome e no Firefox geralmente é (ou era) diferente o elemento que possui o scrollbar padrão

**Devo ressaltar**, se tem um scrollbar horizontal que não devia existir é porque tem um elemento que estar excedendo a largura da página, então usar coisas como `overflow` é só gambiarra, você tem que IDENTIFICAR o elemento que esta ultrapassando os limites do *view-port* usando o DevTools do seu navegador

- Aperte F12 (geralmente) e abra o DevTools
- Role a página ao máximo que puder para a direita
- Selecione a ferramenta de selecionar elementos: [image: inspecionar elementos]
- Vá passando o mouse no lado direito da página, você irá com certeza encontrar o elemento

Answer (score 0):

Poderia tentar dessa forma, JeanExtreme002.

::-webkit-scrollbar {
overflow-y:hidden;
}

Comment: O espaço em branco onde fica o *scrollbar* ainda permance. O que eu quero é o *scrollbar* completamente removido.